# How to make appear my app in activity view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to add youtube sharing in my app.When user share any video, in the activity view my app should appear.How to do ?
Suggest me some tutorials.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add some implemented code

Comment: Chek this url http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-share-things-with-a-uiactivityviewcontroller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by building a share extension for you app. Please refer to this [link](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/share-extension-in-ios-8). Happy Coding.